# Exclude all sub-directories using find

Tags: terminal

This is what look like my directory structure :

```
 pi
    |___
        |
        folder1
         |____otherfolder1
        folder2
         |____otherfolder2
        folder3
         |____otherfolder3
```

I used this command :

```
find /home/pi -name "*folder*" -type d
```

But I only want folder1,2,3 but not subfolders (ohterfolder1,2,3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using -maxdepth 1

```
find /home/pi -maxdepth 1 -name "*folder*" -type d
```